# No audio on Facebook, YouTube Android app when on 4G

Tags: audio, mobile-data, google-pixel, 4g

My Pixel 5 audio is working while on WiFi at home.

When I'm not on WiFi and using 4G, any video on Facebook or YouTube has no audio.

On Facebook I can turn the audio off and on for each video, doing so makes no difference.

I can't see volume controls anywhere in the YouTube app, either on each video, or in the app settings.

In Android Settings > Audio, all audio levels are high.

Why would audio not work on any Facebook or YouTube videos while on 4G?

The problem has followed me to a new Pixel 6a too.

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Can you be more detailed as to how you are checking 4G vs WiFi, i.e. different locations, perhaps using 4G in a vehicle with a paired but incompatible bluetooth audio system. Also can you play and hear audio from the Chrome browser/other apps while on 4G in different locations.

Comment: Just saw your answer now @MorrisonChang, after discovering the car's Bluetooth system was involved

Comment: @ChanganAuto - I posted the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the cause of the problem.

Both phones were paired via Bluetooth to the car's sound system whenever I was in the car.

The car will only play audio from the phone when the car's sound system is specifically set to do so (-vs- playing FM or AM radio).

So the solution is to either:

- unpair the phone from the car
- or switch the car's audio system to play via Bluetooth.